# Updating a map marker in android

Tags: android, android-mapview, google-maps-markers, marker

Using Google Maps Android API v2, I can update my marker's position by getting the `Marker` from a hashMap and then calling:

```
Marker marker = hashMap.get(someId);
marker.setTitle("Title");
marker.setSnippet("Snippet");
marker.setPosition(new LatLng(newLatitude, newLongitude));
```

However, if the marker is selected when this is called, the title and snippet will only update if I click off the marker and reselect it. Is there anyway to tell the map to refresh the data in the marker bubble?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Call `hideInfoWindow()` immediately followed by a call to `showInfoWindow()`, like this:

```
marker.hideInfoWindow();
marker.showInfoWindow();
```