# how to add a title to a marker after the marker has been added to the google maps in android google maps api

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I am creating an app which can show the navigation path between two points in the google maps API in Android. When user clicks on the map somewhere, a marker is added at that place. When user clicks 2nd time, another marker is added and optimized navigation path is shown to the user in my application.

There is a JSON file provided by https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/ which contains address of origin and destination. I have parsed that JSON file and stored the addresses.

Now the problem is, I have added the origin and destination markers already to the map by clicking on the map. and I want to provide title (address) to both the markers. But I guess we can not change the details after we have added the markers in the map.

Please reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can refre this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132174/always-show-map-marker-title-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change marker tile by `marker.setTitle("title")` method and then refresh the marker-view by following

```
marker.hideInfoWindow();
marker.showInfoWindow();
```

[This question may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15249720/4565874)

[with this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16290657/4565874)

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep Marker after adding MarkerOptions to the map.
Let me show you an example of what should be done:

```
 GoogleMap map = ... // get a map.
 // Add a marker at San Francisco.
 Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
 .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
 .title("San Francisco")
 .snippet("Population: 776733"));

 marker.setTitle("MY MARKER'S NEW TITLE")
```

Sources:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker?hl=pt-br

[Changing a Marker's text in Android GoogleMaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009863/changing-a-markers-text-in-android-googlemaps)

Answer (score -1):

```
 marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("Perth")
                .flat(true));
         .snippet("Population: 1,738,800"));
```

.title for setting tittle and .snippet for little details under title aand this code to method `addMarkersToMap()` and if you click on marker it'll appear and disppear